# How do I give a click event to submenu in dropdown of ant design?

Tags: antd

I'm using ant-design, dropdown. + React, Typescript

For example, if you click on the label 'teamA' of 'item' in the current code, you want the function 'handleMenuClick' to run.

```
// this is my data.
const items: MenuProps['items'] = [
  {
    key: '1',
    label: 'Company',
  },
  {
    key: '2',
    label: 'teamA',
    children: [
      {
        key: '2-1',
        label: 'teamA-a',
      },
    ],
  }
];
```

```
// FilterTeam.tsx
const handleMenuClick: MenuProps['onClick'] = (e) => {
  message.info('Click on menu item.');
  console.log('click', e);
};

const menuProps = {
  items,
  onClick: handleMenuClick,
};

const FilterTeam = () => {
  return (
    <StyledDropdown menu={menuProps} trigger={['click']}>
      <Button>
        <Space>
          {items[3]?.label}
          <DownOutlined />
        </Space>
      </Button>
    </StyledDropdown>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use props

```
onTitleClick: () => {console.log("test")}
```

and Menuprops you use props from antd

```
import type { MenuProps } from 'antd';
```

and this example

```
  const items: MenuProps['items'] = [
  {
    key: '2',
    label: 'sub menu',
    onTitleClick: () => {console.log("test")}, //here example
    children: [
      {
        key: '2-1',
        label: '3rd menu item',
      },
      {
        key: '2-2',
        label: '4th menu item',
      },
    ],
  }
];


<Dropdown menu={{ items }}>
    <a onClick={(e) => e.preventDefault()}>
      <Space>
        Cascading menu
        <DownOutlined />
      </Space>
    </a>
  </Dropdown>
```